# Z-score calculation/standardisation using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I come across this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-vHQub0NXI4&t) and it bugs me.

Essentially, at [5:50](https://youtu.be/-vHQub0NXI4?t=351), they calculate Z-score for the whole data frame by the following snippet:

```
df_z = (df - df.describle.T['mean'])/df.describle.T['std']
```

It is a neat and beautiful line.

However, `df.describle.T` looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7yryZ.png) and `df` looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/siT5N.png)

`df.describle.T['mean']` and `df.describle.T['std']` are two individual series, which take the `df` columns name as index and `describle` statistic parameters as columns, and `df` is an ordinary `pd.DataFrame`which has numercial index and columns names in the right places.

My question is: how does that line make sense when they are not matching at all, in particular, how do they ensure that every variable example (x_i) matches their mean or std?

Thank you.

Comment: I see `(x - train_stats['mean']) / train_stats['std']`, which makes sense in my eyes.

Comment: The transpose (.T) is only happening because in your df and df.describle rows and columns are changed, no?

Comment: Side note: this looks like `t score` and not `z score`

Comment: @Nils Werner see [here](https://youtu.be/-vHQub0NXI4?t=307), `train_stats = train_stats.transpose()`. and even it is not transposed, it does not make sense to me as i expect `df` - `series`, given they have the same number of row, should be a row by row operation. While the `describe` returns a df which has `shape` (p, c) where `p` is the number of parameters, and `c` is the number of columns. in other words, even they are subtracted row by row, the result does not make any sense since col_i is not only subtracting it means but also other parameters.